# C# Bot Framework and maximum upload limit

Tags: c#, post, azure-web-app-service, botframework, http-status-code-500

Having same issue with Botframework and C#, trying to upload images that are queried against a custom vision service. Any images that are bigger than 4MB do not POST and I am greeted with error code 500 internal server error. Bear in mind it works locally using the botframework-emulator.

I have tried editing the php.ini (that had max upload set to size 8MB by default anyway)

```
[PHP]
engine = On
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 8000
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 17
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = Off
expose_php = On
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = -1
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = On
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 1024M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[intl]
[sqlite]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = On
[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = wincache
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatibility_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off
[Assertion]
[COM]
com.allow_dcom = 0
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[mcrypt]
[dba]
[opcache]
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=20
[curl]
curl.cainfo = D:\cacert\cacert.pem
[WebPIChanges]
cgi.force_redirect=0
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
fastcgi.impersonate=1
fastcgi.logging=0
max_execution_time=300
date.timezone=America/Los_Angeles
extension_dir="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\"
[wincache]
wincache.srwlocks=0
wincache.ocachesize=15
wincache.maxfilesize=512
wincache.fcachesize=128
wincache.reroute_enabled=0
[ExtensionList]
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_wincache.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
error_log=D:\home\LogFiles\php_errors.log 
upload_tmp_dir=D:\local\Temp 
session.save_path=D:\local\Temp 
wincache.filemapdir=D:\local\Temp 
short_open_tag=On
```

and web.config file

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" executionTimeout="500" maxRequestLength="20480"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>

    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: To confirm. Is your PHP backed service hosted on Azure Web Apps? Did you configurate the PHP configuration follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure?

Comment: The PHP is hosted on Azure web apps, I have changed the php.ini file to the be located at root directory (due to it's protection level) and changed configs so the web app would point to this newly created php.ini

I've give the issue to an azure tech support person along with my phpinfo and he does not believe it's the PHP that's the problem. His test azure site actually allows for uploads >4MB. I will post a solution if we get it fixed.

Comment: For clarification the phpinfo says Loaded Configuration File: D:\home\site\php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Channels have their own limits on upload size. for example [Skype](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34644/skype-file-sharing-file-types-size-and-time-limits)

> There are size limits to files, and some types of files may require
>   separate software or an app to view them. As long as your friend has
>   enough storage space, they can access and save any files you send them
>   for 30 days. What is the file size limit in Skype? There is a 300 MB
>   file size limit on shared files

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

maxRequestLength in Kilobytes.

Comment: Tried this and didn't work, from what I've gathered it's not the php.ini file or the web.config :/

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to Direct Line
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/789 and is yet to be fixed